# How to use tag questions in sentences containing: 'as well as', 'along with', 'neither....nor'... etc.?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, syntactic-analysis

I need the rules of using tag questions in sentences containing: *as well as*, *along with*, *neither....nor...*, *either....or*... etc.

For instance:

> I as well as my friends am going to the party, *_*?

Comment: What do you want to ask? You don't need a tag question at the end of your sentence if you're not asking a question.

Comment: The tag which turns the statement into a question matches the subject, which you have already decided is ***I*** (because of the verb *am*) so it's *aren't I*. But your sentence is not a construction which is used very often, if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"as well as" does not make the subject plural.

> He, as well as she, is a chef.

So this **is** correct:

> I, as well as my friends, am going to the party, right?

- I am quite sure that "as well as"-like phrases are appositives, so you'd need the comma.

This is wrong:

> I, as well as my friends, are going to the party, right?

Or you could just ask,

> Am I ... ?